# NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog, heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, carrierwave, fog

I am trying to use carrierwave, fog and AWS for my image uploading on Heroku. Pretty common...I even have it set up successfully for another app. However when I delpoy to heroku I'm getting this error:

Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.3.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'devise'
gem 'tinymce-rails-imageupload', github: 'PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
 gem 'mini_magick'
 gem 'carrierwave'
 gem 'fog' 
 gem 'figaro'


 gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
 gem 'bootstrap'
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'mini_racer'

 gem 'stripe'
 gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false


# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

application.yml

amazon:
  service: S3
  aws_access_key_id: "key"
  aws_secret_access_key: "key"
  region: "us-east-2"
  AWS_BUCKET: "bucket"

in the config initializers...
fog.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: 'aws_access_key_id',
    aws_secret_access_key: 'aws_secret_access_key',
    region: 'us-east-2'
  }

      config.fog_directory = 'books4reviews'

  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage = :file
    end
  end

  # Use AWS storage if in production
  if Rails.env.production?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage = :fog
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the build log:

```
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:78:in `eval'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
       (eval):1:in `storage'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:78:in `eval'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:78:in `storage'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:7:in `<class:AvatarUploader>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:1:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/app/models/user.rb:2:in `<class:User>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise.rb:316:in `get'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise.rb:346:in `new'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise.rb:346:in `add_mapping'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/config/routes.rb:33:in `block in <main>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:414:in `draw'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `each'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_cc315cc16be89c43f2c799ba61fa4e8e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I've been googling this and looking at similar questions on stackoverflow and can't figure it out. I'm sure it's something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered this problem repeatedly across various projects, and I typically fix it by defining the `CarrierWave::Storage::Fog` class myself, as an empty class, in an initializer.

Amazingly this seems to work, and it doesn't seem to interfere with Rails' ability to load the real class:

```
# config/initializers/fix_fog.rb
module CarrierWave; module Storage; class Fog; end; end; end
```

I've deployed this several times, [since at least February 2016](https://github.com/meagar/motive/blob/master/config/initializers/fix_fox.rb). It doesn't seem like a great solution, and I'd be interested in alternatives.

Comment: I've never had the opportunity to share my solution on Stack Overflow, though I've used it on a few projects at various workplaces. I'd love to know if a better alternative exists.

Comment: Good solution! Very nice. Easy fix. Very interesting....I'm sure many others googling this problem will be super happy to come across your solution.

Comment: We did some re-arranging of hierarchy within the fog project, it may be that carrierwave is due for a patch to fix this. If somebody wanted to work on this and had questions, I'd certainly be happy to support it.

Comment: Thanks! I have problem in requiring fog-aws on old RoR 3.2 app because of require of 'fog' in carrierwave 0.11+ versions: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1925/files
And I wanted to left 0.10.0 version in my project because it requires mimemagic which is eating about 40Mb of RAM alone without any usage.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Add `require 'carrierwave/storage/fog'` at the top of your config/initializers/fog.rb file.

Comment: I tried that before I asked the stackoverflow question and it doesn't work. And the answer I accepted allows my code to sucessfully deploy to heroku but it crashes immediatly when you launch it. Ready to throw in the towel with aws, carrierwave and fog. May find a different solution

Comment: Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)...that's what I get in the rails console when I want a closer look at the heroku logs since the h10 crash code doesn't help at all

Comment: You sure, your app is crashing because of this? You are using active storage or carrierwave?

Comment: @dmberko11 If my answer doesn't really fix the problem, you don't have to accept it. Leaving no answer accepted is more likely to generate new answers.